# :hover doesn't work properly in Elementor

Tags: html, css, hover, elementor

Hey guys here is the page where I would like the text to completely disappear when a user passes the mouse over it so that there is only the image that is visible, but the problem is that **:hover** makes disappear the image as well and besides it goes beyond the image borders.

Could you please help me out?

Thanks!

http://alicestarshipforpublishing.bestrank.it/bozza-homepage

Comment: can you put a simple example here and explain more

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.elementor-element.elementor-element-163082e.elementor-absolute.elementor-widget.elementor-widget-text-editor.elementor-motion-effects-parent.elementor-motion-effects-perspective:hover .elementor-text-editor {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```